# Firebase Authentication - Logged In User Is Null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have managed to setup a custom login system using Firebase. The user enters email/password and is redirected to the main page(which is private). I am having issue with onAuthStateChanged after logging in. When I check the auth state after logging into the main page, i get invalid user (null). The firebase dashboard shows I have logged in successfully but onAuthStateChanged is the opposite.

I am trying to check if a user is logged in to my html pages, if not I want to redirect them to the login page. I like how the authentication works in firebase but I need to protect my html pages not my divs (which is what the vast majority of firebase auth tutorials show).

If anyone has an easier way to password protect a web directory that looks nicer than HTaccess, please advise (I am not crazy about using wordpress for password protection, but its an option). Otherwise, I guess I will have to do this in PHP. Thanks in advance!

```js
(function () {
   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // User is signed in.
         console.log(user);
         console.log('A user is logged in.');
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('Invalid user. Redirecting to root.');
        window.location.replace('../index.html');
      }
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to a new page, Firebase will have to initialize again. As part of that it will try to restore the user's authentication state, but this requires a call to the server which takes time.

For that reason the `onAuthStateChanged` listener will initially fire with `null` as the current user (and `auth.currentUser` is set to `null`). Then once the user is signed in, the listener fires again with the `user` object for that user.

If you want to detect this initial state, you can either store some token value in the browser's local storage that you can check for yourself on the new page, or you could set a time-out for when you expect the user to be re-signed in and only then navigate away to the `index.html` page.

Comment: A timeout sounds like a good path to try, I had no idea load time would play a factor. Thank you for the insight, Frank!

Comment: Setting the time delay had no effect, once the duration ends, onAuthStateChanged fires and the user is null. I need to make sure users can't access my html files before authentication. Right now, a quick google search would give a backdoor lol. I don't suppose there's a way to get firebase to work with htaccess? PS> I already have a host

Comment: I am assuming the only way to ensure all my pages are protected and only accessible by password is to have firebase host my files. I will use PHP for my login solution and scrap my firebase app. Learning is fun =D

Comment: 1) The delay should be before you decide to navigate away. Attach the listener straight away when the page loads. 2)  "I need to make sure users can't access my html files before authentication." There is no way to do this on Firebase Hosting. Any files there are accessible by everyone worldwide.

Comment: Hi Frank. I think I sorted my issue out. I uploaded my web prototype and it's working! I guess when FiB checks for login, it's checking on the web, not locally =0 If I try to access my html pages without Firebase Auth, the user is kicked to the root where they can request access. Yea, I know my files can still be accessed, but I am working towards keeping my content from being indexed by search engines etc. As it stands, navigation is dependent on authentication. I have a ways to go but I am happy with the results!